# can we create token base authentication without creating database in asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

i want to create token base authentication using asp.net web API2 but my requirement is ,i do not want to create database for storing the token or other credential of user i just want to authenticate the user is valid or not.

please help me 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Valid in what way? And how do you propose to know if they are "valid" if you don't have some authoritative source to check the token or credentials they present against?

Comment: Was editing the comment to expand and ran out of time: I guess the short answer to your question, though, is yes. But you will have to store the user information/credentials somewhere. A database, if set up right, can be a fairly secure way to do that, unlike XML or a text file which have no built-in facility to obfuscate or protect the sensitive parts of the information.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin. You would need to store the data somehow, and an alternative would be a flat file. But then you have to build in your own security, which is not a task undertaken lightly. It may make more sense to do some research and find a library/tutorial that assists with this issue. OAuth2 would be a good starting point.